# Handling optional data in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

How would you handle data where some parts are optional? For example this data:

```
[
    {
        width: 10,
        height: 20,
        margin: { top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10: left: 10 }
    },
    {
        width: 10,
        height: 20
    }
]
```

So I'd like to only append some SVG rect when `margin` is available. I could use the visibility attribute to hide it, but this would mean I have unnecessary nodes and have to write null checking code to avoid javascript errors.

```
var svgobj = svg.selectAll('.object').data(objects);

var svgobjEnter = svgobj.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'object');

svgobjEnter.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'margin');
    .attr('width', function(d) { return d.width + d.margin.left + d.margin.right; })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.height + d.margin.top + d.margin.bottom; })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your data to do this:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(objects.filter(function(d) { return d.margin != undefined; }))
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
// etc
```